# Jquery Post Bypass Validation

Tags: jquery, validation, post

Is there a way to bypass the validation on this?

My purpose is to allow any new number without having a hard time registering a new number on that site and wait for the sms verification code. That is why I want to bypass the checking/validation of number so I can register a new number to their web based registration for text/call promo.

Here's part of the code:

```
`addPromo:function(){
    var a=$(" #keyword").val();
    var d=$("#"+Aftersale.Ui.Plan.namespace+"_serviceNumber").val();
    var b=$("#"+Aftersale.Ui.Plan.namespace+"_email").val();
    var c=$("#"+Aftersale.Ui.Plan.namespace+"_hashKey").val();
    var f="email="+b+"&serviceNumber="+d+"&keyword="+a+"&transId="+c+"&serviceMethod=ServiceCall&callback=?";
    var g=$("#promoType")[0].selectedIndex;
    var e=$("#keyword").val();

    if(Aftersale.Validation.Plan.validatePromos(g,e))
    {
    ServicesProxy.Ajax.addPromo($.trim(f))
    }
}`
```

I want to bypass checking of transid. It is on hash format, but there's no transid or hashkey on the site where that code came from so I can dynamically change the serviceNumber and email.

But today if I change email and number the error says "INVALID INPUT" and I noticed that they add hashkey or transid.

Can I bypass the validation?

Here's the code for ServicesProxy.Ajax.addPromo($.trim(f)):

```
   addPromo:function(a)
{
$.ajax(
{
url:Ajax.url+"ServiceCallServlet",dataType:Ajax.dataType,type:Ajax.type,data:a,success:function(d){var b=d.FLAG;var c=d.MESSAGE;if(b){Aftersale.Ui.hideMessages();Aftersale.Ui.showSuccessMessage(c)}else{Aftersale.Ui.hideMessages();Aftersale.Ui.showErrorMessage(c)}},error:function(b,c){Aftersale.Ui.showErrorMessage(b)}
})
}
```

Comment: Trying to by-pass someones validation doesn't sound right to me. Could you elaborate a bit more on what you are actually doing?

Comment: Im tryin to bypass the validation or checking of number and emails, this site is a webbased registration for text & call promo, i need to bypass the validation so i can change the value of email and number so i can able to register a new number to their text & call promo, the purpose of this to eliminate the time that i need to register again to that site. by the way im using javascript: on address bar to call the function so i can register on their promo with having a hard time to register a new one

Comment: So you are basically trying to hack the site?!

Comment: Not actually hack, because even if i do this i can't register on their Text/Call Promo if i havent LOAD on my SIM Card, i just want to make it easier, i just want to register a new sim (with LOAD) on their Text/Call Promo without registering a new account

Comment: Can anyone help me with this? thanks